# GitHub Actions reusable workflow pulling scripts from repo

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I've got two repositories with workflows.

- myOrg/reusable-workflows

  - Contains reusable workflows and scripts to be run to interact with some services.
- myOrg/workflow-initiator

  - Contains main body of code and calls the reusable workflows.

Workflow Initiator calls a reusable workflow in reusable-workflows. Reusable workflows also has a bunch of nodeJS & python scripts. Inside the reusable workflow is the following:

```
    steps:
      - name: Checkout files
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          repository: 'myOrg/reusable-workflows'
          path: 'workflows'
      - name: Do Something
        run: |
          echo Hello World
```

I find that if I don't tell it to checkout the reusable workflow, if checks out the workflow initiator instead. However the above will throw an error saying it's unable to work out the default branch.

```
Determining the default branch
  Retrieving the default branch name
  Not Found
  Waiting 14 seconds before trying again
  Retrieving the default branch name
  Not Found
  Waiting 17 seconds before trying again
```

I need to make sure that information from git (especially PR information) is being pulled from myOrg/workflow-initiator into the reusable workflow in myOrg/reusable-workflow